# Spring defaultContentType ignored

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 3.2.4 application with the following mvc setup:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport  {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        configurer.mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        configurer.mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    }
```

when I access my controller's url like /rest/products.json I get JSON response and via /rest/products.xml I get XML as expected.

But when I accesss /rest/products I get XML, but I expected JSON as I set that as default content type.

This seems to be ignored by Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html#defaultContentType%28org.springframework.http.MediaType%29) says:

> This content type will be used when neither the request path
>   extension, nor a request parameter, nor the Accept header could help
>   determine the requested content type.

So there are at least three ways to tell Spring which format you are trying to receive. My guess would be that you are still telling Spring somehow that you want to get the data in XML, maybe in a requests parameter or - more likely as it is not that visible - in a header.

Try checking the headers of your request.

Comment: I was calling it from the browser which indeed sent the accpet headers html and xml, and hence causing the rest interface to return xml response instead of json/